# Rust CLI for playing Wordle

Tags: beginner, rust, wordle

I wrote the following CLI for playing the popular word game - [Wordle](https://www.powerlanguage.co.uk/wordle/). Wordle is a word game in which players are trying to guess a 5 letter word. Each turn they guess one 5 letter word, and for each letter are told that it either isn't in the word, is in the word, but not here, or is correctly placed.

This CLI attempts to play the game by taking a wordlist, guessing words that cut down the remaining words (e.g. by maximising the number of new characters in it) until there are only two possible words left.

Users can either provide the answer up front using the `--answer` flag, or respond interactively to each guess, specifying whether it is present, absent or correct.

I'm primarily looking for feedback on how "rusty" the code is and how it can be made more idiomatic. In particular:

- is the borrowing right? I felt like a lot of the time I was just making changes to make the compiler happy!
- are the tests structured in the normal way?
- is the module breakdown suitable?
- are there well known libraries I should be using?

I am experienced with other languages (C++/C#) but new to Rust.

**main.rs**

```rust
mod game;
mod cli;
mod interactive_solver;
mod non_interactive_solver;
mod player;

fn main() {
    cli::run_cli();
}
```

**game.rs**

```rust
pub const GAME_WORD_LENGTH: usize = 5;

#[derive(Copy, Clone, Ord, PartialOrd, Eq, PartialEq, Debug)]
pub enum LetterResponse {
    Correct,
    InWord,
    NotInWord,
}

pub struct GuessResponse {
    pub letter_responses: Vec<LetterResponse>,
}

pub fn is_guess_correct(response: &GuessResponse) -> bool {
    response
        .letter_responses
        .iter()
        .all(|&l| l == LetterResponse::Correct)
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod is_guess_correct_tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn all_correct_is_correct() {
        let response = GuessResponse {
            letter_responses: [LetterResponse::Correct; 5].to_vec(),
        };
        assert!(is_guess_correct(&response));
    }

    #[test]
    fn one_in_correct_is_not_correct() {
        let response = GuessResponse {
            letter_responses: [
                LetterResponse::Correct,
                LetterResponse::Correct,
                LetterResponse::Correct,
                LetterResponse::InWord,
                LetterResponse::Correct,
            ]
            .to_vec(),
        };
        assert!(!is_guess_correct(&response));
    }
}
```

**cli.rs**

```rust
use crate::game;
use crate::game::GuessResponse;
use crate::interactive_solver;
use crate::non_interactive_solver;
use crate::player;
use clap::Parser;
use std::fs;

#[derive(Parser, Debug)]
#[clap(about, version, author)]
struct Args {
    #[clap(long, default_value = "words_alpha.txt")]
    word_list_path: String,

    #[clap(long)]
    answer: Option<String>,
}

pub fn run_cli() {
    let args = Args::parse();

    let word_list = read_word_list(args.word_list);
    let verifier: Box<dyn Fn(&str) -> GuessResponse> = match args.answer {
        Some(word) => Box::new(move |guess: &str| {
            let answer_word = word.clone();
            non_interactive_solver::non_interactive_solver(guess, answer_word)
        }),
        None => Box::new(move |guess: &str| interactive_solver::interactive_solver(&guess)),
    };

    let sln = player::solve(&word_list, verifier);
    println!("Solution: {:?}", sln.guess_sequence);
}

fn read_word_list(word_list_file_name: String) -> Vec<String> {
    fs::read_to_string(word_list_file_name)
        .expect("Error reading file")
        .split_ascii_whitespace()
        .filter(|s| s.len() == game::GAME_WORD_LENGTH)
        .filter(|s| s.chars().all(|c| c.is_alphabetic()))
        .map(str::to_string)
        .collect()
}
```

**interactive_solver.rs**

```rust
use crate::game;
use crate::game::GuessResponse;
use crate::game::LetterResponse;
use std::io;

pub fn interactive_solver(guess: &str) -> GuessResponse {
    println!("Guess: {}", guess);
    let mut response = String::new();
    println!("Type a {} letter response - y: correct, . - in word, x - not involved", game::GAME_WORD_LENGTH);

    loop {
        io::stdin()
            .read_line(&mut response)
            .expect("Failed to read line");
        response.pop();
        match response.len() {
            game::GAME_WORD_LENGTH => {
                let parsed_response = parse_user_response(&response);
                match parsed_response {
                    Ok(response) => return response,
                    Err(e) => println!("Invalid string: {}", e),
                }
            }

            _ => {
                println!("Enter exactly {} characters, {}", game::GAME_WORD_LENGTH, response.len())
            }
        }
    }
}

fn parse_user_response(response_str: &String) -> Result<GuessResponse, String> {
    if response_str.len() != game::GAME_WORD_LENGTH {
        panic!(format!("Must call parse_user_response with exactly {} characters", game::GAME_WORD_LENGTH));
    }
    let mapped_response: Result<Vec<_>, _> = response_str
        .chars()
        .map(|char| match char {
            'y' => Ok(LetterResponse::Correct),
            '.' => Ok(LetterResponse::InWord),
            'x' => Ok(LetterResponse::NotInWord),
            x => Err(format!("Invalid character: {}", x)),
        })
        .collect();

    return match mapped_response {
        Ok(x) => Ok(GuessResponse {
            letter_responses: x.to_vec(),
        }),
        Err(e) => Err(format!("Invalid response: {}", e)),
    };
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod parse_user_response_tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn valid_string_parsed_correctly() {
        // If I inline this, it is apparently still needed for checking response.is_ok (lazy eval of parse_user_response?)
        let user_input = String::from("y.x.x");
        let response = parse_user_response(&user_input);
        assert!(response.is_ok());
        assert_eq!(
            response.unwrap().letter_responses,
            vec![
                LetterResponse::Correct,
                LetterResponse::InWord,
                LetterResponse::NotInWord,
                LetterResponse::InWord,
                LetterResponse::NotInWord
            ]
        );
    }

    #[test]
    fn one_invalid_char_invalid_response() {
        let user_input = String::from("y.xax");
        let response = parse_user_response(&user_input);
        assert!(response.is_err());
    }
}
```

**non_interactive_solver.rs**

```rust
use crate::game::GuessResponse;
use crate::game::LetterResponse;

pub fn non_interactive_solver(guess: &str, answer: String) -> GuessResponse {
    GuessResponse {
        letter_responses: guess
            .chars()
            .enumerate()
            .map(|(index, char)| {
                if answer
                    .chars()
                    .nth(index)
                    .expect("Word length different from guess length")
                    == char
                {
                    return LetterResponse::Correct;
                } else if answer.contains(char) {
                    return LetterResponse::InWord;
                } else {
                    return LetterResponse::NotInWord;
                }
            })
            .collect(),
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod non_interactive_solver_tests {
    use super::*;
    #[test]
    fn words_same_all_correct() {
        let guess = "hello";
        let answer = "hello";
        let result = non_interactive_solver(&guess, String::from(answer));
        assert!(result
            .letter_responses
            .iter()
            .all(|&l| l == LetterResponse::Correct))
    }

    #[test]
    fn letter_in_not_right_place() {
        let guess = "abc";
        let answer = "dea";
        let result = non_interactive_solver(&guess, String::from(answer));
        assert!(result.letter_responses[0] == LetterResponse::InWord);
        assert!(result.letter_responses[1] == LetterResponse::NotInWord);
        assert!(result.letter_responses[2] == LetterResponse::NotInWord);
    }
}
```

**player.rs**

````rust
use crate::game;
use crate::game::GuessResponse;
use crate::game::LetterResponse;
use itertools::Itertools;
use std::collections::HashMap;

pub struct Solution {
    pub guess_sequence: Vec<String>,
}

struct Knowledge {
    guessed_words: Vec<String>,
    correct_letters: Vec<(char, usize)>,
    contained_letters: HashMap<char, Vec<usize>>,
}

fn build_empty_knowledge() -> Knowledge {
    Knowledge {
        guessed_words: vec![],
        correct_letters: vec![],
        contained_letters: HashMap::new(),
    }
}

pub fn solve<VFn>(possbile_words: &Vec<String>, verifier: VFn) -> Solution
where
    VFn: Fn(&str) -> GuessResponse,
{
    solve_rec(possbile_words, verifier, &build_empty_knowledge())
}

fn solve_rec<VFn>(
    possbile_words: &Vec<String>,
    verifier: VFn,
    starting_knowledge: &Knowledge,
) -> Solution
where
    VFn: Fn(&str) -> GuessResponse,
{
    let guess = make_guess(possbile_words, starting_knowledge);
    let response = verifier(&guess);
    let new_knowledge = apply_learning(starting_knowledge, &guess, &response);

    match game::is_guess_correct(&response) {
        true => Solution {
            guess_sequence: new_knowledge.guessed_words,
        },
        false => solve_rec(possbile_words, verifier, &new_knowledge),
    }
}

fn apply_learning(knowledge: &Knowledge, guess: &String, response: &GuessResponse) -> Knowledge {
    let mut new_words = knowledge.guessed_words.clone();
    new_words.push(guess.to_string());
    Knowledge {
        guessed_words: new_words,
        correct_letters: knowledge
            .correct_letters
            .iter()
            .map(|t| t.clone())
            .chain(
                response
                    .letter_responses
                    .iter()
                    .enumerate()
                    .filter(|(_, &char)| char == LetterResponse::Correct)
                    .map(|(index, &_)| (guess.chars().nth(index).unwrap(), index))
                    .collect::<Vec<(char, usize)>>(),
            )
            .collect::<Vec<(char, usize)>>(),
        contained_letters: merge_contained_letters_map(
            &knowledge.contained_letters,
            response
                .letter_responses
                .iter()
                .enumerate()
                .filter(|(_, &char)| char == LetterResponse::InWord)
                .map(|(index, &_)| (guess.chars().nth(index).unwrap(), index)),
        ),
    }
}

fn merge_contained_letters_map<I>(
    original: &HashMap<char, Vec<usize>>,
    newly_tried_letters: I,
) -> HashMap<char, Vec<usize>>
where
    I: Iterator<Item = (char, usize)>,
{
    let mut new_map = original.clone();
    for (char, pos_tried) in newly_tried_letters {
        if new_map.contains_key(&char) {
            let mut current_vec = new_map[&char].clone();
            current_vec.push(pos_tried);
            new_map.insert(char, current_vec);
        } else {
            new_map.insert(char, vec![pos_tried]);
        }
    }
    new_map
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod apply_learning_tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn empty_knowledge_correct_letter_added_to_list_of_correct_letters() {
        let knowledge = build_empty_knowledge();
        let response = GuessResponse {
            letter_responses: [
                LetterResponse::Correct,
                LetterResponse::NotInWord,
                LetterResponse::NotInWord,
            ]
            .to_vec(),
        };
        let new_knowledge = apply_learning(&knowledge, &String::from("abc"), &response);
        assert!(new_knowledge.correct_letters.len() == 1);
        assert!(new_knowledge.correct_letters[0] == ('a', 0));
    }

    #[test]
    fn empty_knowledge_contained_letters_added_to_list_of_contained_letters() {
        let knowledge = build_empty_knowledge();
        let response = GuessResponse {
            letter_responses: [
                LetterResponse::InWord,
                LetterResponse::NotInWord,
                LetterResponse::NotInWord,
            ]
            .to_vec(),
        };
        let new_knowledge = apply_learning(&knowledge, &String::from("abc"), &response);
        assert!(new_knowledge.correct_letters.len() == 0);
        assert!(new_knowledge.contained_letters.len() == 1);
        assert!(new_knowledge.contained_letters.contains_key(&'a'));
        assert_eq!(new_knowledge.contained_letters[&'a'], vec![0]);
    }

    #[test]
    fn knowledge_about_letter_in_word_extended() {
        let knowledge = Knowledge {
            contained_letters: HashMap::from([('a', vec![0])]),
            ..build_empty_knowledge()
        };
        let response = GuessResponse {
            letter_responses: [
                LetterResponse::NotInWord,
                LetterResponse::InWord,
                LetterResponse::NotInWord,
            ]
            .to_vec(),
        };
        let new_knowledge = apply_learning(&knowledge, &String::from("bac"), &response);
        assert!(new_knowledge.correct_letters.len() == 0);
        assert!(new_knowledge.contained_letters.len() == 1);
        assert!(new_knowledge.contained_letters.contains_key(&'a'));
        assert_eq!(new_knowledge.contained_letters[&'a'], vec![0, 1]);
    }
}

fn make_guess(possbile_words: &Vec<String>, knowledge: &Knowledge) -> String {
    let valid_words = possbile_words
        .iter()
        .filter(|w| {
            knowledge
                .correct_letters
                .iter()
                .all(|(char, index)| w.chars().nth(*index).unwrap() == *char)
        })
        .filter(|w| {
            knowledge
                .contained_letters
                .iter()
                .all(|char| w.chars().contains(char.0))
        })
        .filter(|w| {
            knowledge
                .contained_letters
                .iter()
                .all(|(char, tried_indexes)| {
                    tried_indexes
                        .iter()
                        .all(|tried_index| w.chars().nth(*tried_index).unwrap() != *char)
                })
        })
        .filter(|w| !knowledge.guessed_words.contains(w))
        .cloned()
        .collect::<Vec<String>>();
    if valid_words.len() > 2 {
        let guess = revealing_word(&valid_words, &knowledge);
        println!("{} possibilities, trying {}", valid_words.len(), guess);
        guess
    } else {
        valid_words.first().unwrap().to_string()
    }
}

fn revealing_word(possbile_words: &Vec<String>, knowledge: &Knowledge) -> String {
    let letter_frequency = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
        .chars()
        .map(|c| (c, possbile_words.iter().map(|w| w.matches(c).count()).sum()))
        .collect::<HashMap<char, usize>>();

    possbile_words
        .iter()
        .max_by(|w1, w2| {
            let w1_score = word_score(&w1, &letter_frequency, &knowledge);
            let w2_score = word_score(&w2, &letter_frequency, &knowledge);
            w1_score.cmp(&w2_score)
        })
        .unwrap()
        .clone()
}

fn word_score(
    word: &String,
    char_frequence: &HashMap<char, usize>,
    knowledge: &Knowledge,
) -> usize {
    word.chars()
        .unique() // each letter only gets scored once
        .map(|c_in_word| {
            if knowledge.contained_letters.contains_key(&c_in_word) {
                return char_frequence[&c_in_word];
            } else if knowledge
                .correct_letters
                .iter()
                .any(|(letter, _)| *letter == c_in_word)
            {
                return char_frequence[&c_in_word];
            } else if knowledge
                .guessed_words
                .iter()
                .any(|w| w.contains(c_in_word))
            {
                return 0;
            }
            return char_frequence[&c_in_word];
        })
        .sum()
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod make_guess_tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn guessed_one_word_dont_guess_again() {
        let words = [String::from("foo"), String::from("bar")].to_vec();
        let knowledge = Knowledge {
            guessed_words: [String::from("foo")].to_vec(),
            ..build_empty_knowledge()
        };
        let guess = make_guess(&words, &knowledge);
        assert!(guess == "bar");
    }

    #[test]
    fn guessed_one_correct_letter_guess_next_valid_word() {
        let words = [
            String::from("abc"),
            String::from("bcd"),
            String::from("abd"),
        ]
        .to_vec();
        let knowledge = Knowledge {
            guessed_words: vec![String::from("abc")],
            correct_letters: vec![('a', 0)],
            ..build_empty_knowledge()
        };
        let guess = make_guess(&words, &knowledge);
        assert!(guess == "abd");
    }

    #[test]
    fn guessed_one_contained_letter_guess_next_word_that_contains_in_different_position() {
        let words = vec![
            String::from("abc"),
            String::from("bcd"),
            String::from("acd"),
            String::from("bac"),
        ];
        let knowledge = Knowledge {
            guessed_words: vec![String::from("abc")],
            contained_letters: HashMap::from([('a', vec![0])]),
            ..build_empty_knowledge()
        };
        let guess = make_guess(&words, &knowledge);
        assert!(guess == "bac");
    }
}
```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took a quick look at your code and would love to share a few ideas.

### Creating Structs

By convention, when creating a struct you'll usually see this done in a `fn new() -> Self` function that resides in the
structs impl block. So instead of `build_empty_knowledge() -> Knowledge` you might have something like the below:

```rust
impl Knowledge {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Knowledge {
            guessed_words: vec![],
            correct_letters: vec![],
            contained_letters: HashMap::new(),
        }
    }
}
```

Now anytime you'd like to create new knowledge.

```
let knowledge = Knowledge::new();
```

### Expressive Structs

There are a few instances where references to structs are manually being passed to a function. This is fine, but in an attempt
to make the code a bit more expressive, we can move some of these functions into our struct impl block.

Consider the below:

```rust
pub fn is_guess_correct(response: &GuessResponse) -> bool {
    response
        .letter_responses
        .iter()
        .all(|&l| l == LetterResponse::Correct)
}
```

```rust
impl Knowledge {
    pub fn is_correct(&self) -> bool {
        response.letter_responses
            .iter()
            .all(|&l| l == LetterResponse::Correct)
    }
}
```

Now when determining if a response is correct we can just call `response.is_correct()`, which is just a little
nicer to look at I think. I come from a heavy OOP background though so take this with a grain of salt. But I would imagine Rust would also appreciate decisions like this.

### General Readability

There is a ton of inlining statements and closures throughout the code, and it really affects the readability.

Take this snippet for example:

```rust
GuessResponse {
        letter_responses: guess
            .chars()
            .enumerate()
            .map(|(index, char)| {
                if answer
                    .chars()
                    .nth(index)
                    .expect("Word length different from guess length")
                    == char
                {
                    return LetterResponse::Correct;
                } else if answer.contains(char) {
                    return LetterResponse::InWord;
                } else {
                    return LetterResponse::NotInWord;
                }
            })
            .collect(),
    }
```

We could make this a little easier on the eyes and for other readers by naming the inlined boolean expression and by pulling
the somewhat involved closure out into a named function.

```rust
pub fn non_interactive_solver(guess: &str, answer: &str) -> GuessResponse {
    GuessResponse {
        letter_responses: guess
            .chars()
            .enumerate()
            .map(|(index, char)| to_letter_response(answer, char, index))
            .collect(),
    }
}

fn to_letter_response(answer: &str, guess_char: char, guess_index: usize) -> LetterResponse {
    let answer_char = answer
        .chars()
        .nth(guess_index)
        .expect("Word length different from guess length");

    return if answer_char == guess_char {
        LetterResponse::Correct
    } else if answer.contains(guess_char) {
        LetterResponse::InWord
    } else {
        LetterResponse::NotInWord
    };
}
```

By refactoring to the above, as readers we have a bit more context to what these constructs are doing/referencing.
There are a ton of examples similar to this scattered throughout the code base.

### assert! vs assert_eq!

Should probably use the `assert_eq!` macro over `assert!` when comparing equality. `assert_eq!` will give better
message regarding the equality.

```rust
assert!(new_knowledge.correct_letters.len() == 1);
```

```rust
assert_eq!(new_knowledge.correct_letters.len(), 1);
```

### Redundant

When parsing user commands, there is no need to use the `format!` macro. `panic!` supports the same string interpolation.

```rust
panic!("Must call parse_user_response with exactly {} characters", game::GAME_WORD_LENGTH);
```

The possible_words parameter in this function is not being used.

```rust
fn word_score(
    word: &String,
    possible_words: &HashMap<char, usize>,
    knowledge: &Knowledge,
) -> usize { 
    ...
}
```

### Typos

`possbile_words` -> `possible_words`
`char_frequence` -> `char_frequency` or `char_frequencies`

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to provide this feedback - it looks very useful. I have a couple of other things I've spotted which I'll add as an extra answer to compliment this.